# JQuery .submit method not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

In my javascript file, I have a code snippet like:

```
$('<form action="process.php" method="POST">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="amp" value="' + calcJSON.totalAmpDay + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="watt" value="' + calcJSON.maxWattRate + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="dc_volt" value="' + document.number.dc_volt.value + '">' +
'</form>').submit();
```

The above code is included within a function definition. When I click a button, that function is called and then the browser should be redirected to "process.php" page with some POST data.
But only Chrome redirects me to a new page but Firefox wont.

How can this issue be resolved ?

Comment: have you tried adding the DOM element to the page first and then submitting it?  Doing it in 2 steps I mean?

Comment: @cpjolicoeur - Good thought. Also, using `.appendTo()` it could be built, added to DOM, and submitted with a single chain.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It worked.
.appendTo() and .submit() chaining made my task easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this same problem about a week ago. I stand to be corrected but I believe in Firefox the form has to be added to the DOM before it can be submitted. I solved this by setting the CSS to "display: none" and added the form to an arbitrary element on the page before running the submit method.

Answer (score 1):

Alert (or console.log) the -

```
var formtext ='<form action="process.php" method="POST">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="amp" value="' + calcJSON.totalAmpDay + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="watt" value="' + calcJSON.maxWattRate + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="dc_volt" value="' + document.number.dc_volt.value + '">' +
'</form>'
alert(formtext);
```

string before submitting the form. Does the string look like a valid form definition?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion for good, debug it with firebug to see the error and append it to discussion to see what is actually happening.That helps to pinpoint the problem and help. See:[firebug breakpoint](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html)